# simple-form button for boolean ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Need help to make a simple form button (not for submit) but for boolean choice. like the :radio_buttons but i don't want to show the yes/know checkbox. Just need a button and switch from NO to YES on click.

Thks

Comment: seems like you need toggle button http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: You should post your code, what you attempted, and exactly what problem you're having. Generic "do this for me" questions are usually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You need checkbox anyway. Checkbox has been created for boolean values.

Create form with checkbox + button. Click on button should change state of checkbox. Here some pseudocode:

```
$('#my_button').on('click', function(){
  $('#my_check_box').click(); 
});
```

In general you just delegate click to checkbox via button.